# How to play a wave file or sound file using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a wave file that I want to play using VBA. Please help me to create a button that when clicked on plays the wave file.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way for WAV files.  Put ****[this code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PlaySound.aspx)**** in a regular code module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 _
    Lib "winmm.dll" _
    Alias "sndPlaySoundA" ( _
        ByVal lpszSoundName As String, _
        ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Sub PlayTheSound(ByVal WhatSound As String)
    If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = "" Then
        ' WhatSound is not a file. Get the file named by
        ' WhatSound from the Windows\Media directory.
        WhatSound = Environ("SystemRoot") & "\Media\" & WhatSound
        If InStr(1, WhatSound, ".") = 0 Then
            ' if WhatSound does not have a .wav extension,
            ' add one.
            WhatSound = WhatSound & ".wav"
        End If
        If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
            Beep            ' Can't find the file. Do a simple Beep.
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        ' WhatSound is a file. Use it.
    End If

    sndPlaySound32 WhatSound, 0&    ' Finally, play the sound.
End Sub
```

Now, you can play any wav file through any other macro by calling that routine above and feeding in any filename found in the /Media folder:

```
Sub PlayIt()
    Select Case Range("A1").Value
        Case "good"
            PlayTheSound "chimes.wav"
        Case "bad"
            PlayTheSound "chord.wav"
        Case "great"
            PlayTheSound "tada.wav"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Play around with that.

Here's a sample file where I use that to dramatically reveal random names and tasks for the day, it is attached to a button like you plan to do:

**[Random Task List with AUDIO Reveal](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5yK6SOQAy-qYUZXZ0VkWmhraFE)**