# Play Sound in Excel depending on value with a button

Tags: vba, excel, audio

VBA is not my strength, yet I would like to get a Excel sheet where A1 might contain the word "Hello" or "World" or the number 1, and depending on that content a sound file should be played when clicking a button that is next to it. The wav files are located in a specific subfolder where the excel file is.

I’m using Excel (64 bit) version. I was already checking this page:
[How to play a wave file or sound file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443801/how-to-play-a-wave-file-or-sound-file-using-vba)

And tried the following (64 bit compatible):

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
  ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
  ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub PlayTheSound(ByVal WhatSound As String)
    If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = "" Then
        ' WhatSound is not a file. Get the file named by
        ' WhatSound from the Windows\Media directory.
        WhatSound = Environ("SystemRoot") & "\Media\" & WhatSound
        If InStr(1, WhatSound, ".") = 0 Then
            ' if WhatSound does not have a .wav extension,
            ' add one.
            WhatSound = WhatSound & ".wav"
        End If
        If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
            Beep            ' Can't find the file. Do a simple Beep.
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        ' WhatSound is a file. Use it.
    End If

    sndPlaySound32 WhatSound, 0&    ' Finally, play the sound.
End Sub

Sub PlayIt()
    Select Case Range("A1").Value
        Case "Hello"
            PlayTheSound "chimes.wav"
        Case "World"
            PlayTheSound "chord.wav"
        Case 1
            PlayTheSound "tada.wav"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Yet, I get an error

> Argument not optional

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What line is the error? `(ByVal lpszName As String, _
  ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long)` looks like you're missing one of the 3 args in this function ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I know I played a bit with sndPlaySound32(x,x,x). But actually I was coming from that file provided here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443801/how-to-play-a-wave-file-or-sound-file-using-vba

I only added the 64 bit condition in the beginning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because you are calling the function with 2 arguments when the function expects 3. If you want to call `sndPlaySound32` like this

```
sndPlaySound32 WhatSound, 0&    ' Finally, play the sound.
```

Then you need you need to change the function signatures to have just the 2 arguments per the question you [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443801/how-to-play-a-wave-file-or-sound-file-using-vba) - like this:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#End If
```

So the full working code is:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub PlayTheSound(ByVal WhatSound As String)
    If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = "" Then
        ' WhatSound is not a file. Get the file named by
        ' WhatSound from the Windows\Media directory.
        WhatSound = Environ("SystemRoot") & "\Media\" & WhatSound
        If InStr(1, WhatSound, ".") = 0 Then
            ' if WhatSound does not have a .wav extension,
            ' add one.
            WhatSound = WhatSound & ".wav"
        End If
        If Dir(WhatSound, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
            Beep            ' Can't find the file. Do a simple Beep.
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        ' WhatSound is a file. Use it.
    End If

    sndPlaySound32 WhatSound, 0&    ' Finally, play the sound.
End Sub

Sub PlayIt()
    Select Case Range("A1").Value
        Case "Hello"
            PlayTheSound "chimes.wav"
            'PlayTheSound "chime.wav"
        'Case "World"
            'PlayTheSound "chord.wav"
        'Case 1
            'PlayTheSound "tada.wav"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This works now. Just change the line chime.wav to chimes.wav otherwise it wont find the file. Thank you!