# error 424 on a = My.Computer.Audio.Play ("C/***/***/***/cossack_sandvich.wav", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)

Tags: vba

here is the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 If (ToggleButton1.Value = True) Then

  a=My.Computer.Audio.Play("C/use44/et44/sh444/cossack_sandvich.wav",AudioPlayModeW
aitToComplete)

ElseIf (TextBox1.Value = "goals") Then

s = MsgBox("write down your goals", vbYesNo, "goals")

End If

If (s = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then

m = InputBox("", "goals", "", 50, 50)

End If

End Function
```

> error 424 object required at
>   a=My.Computer.Audio.Play("C/u444/et444/sh44/cossack_sandvich.wav",AudioPlayModeW
>   aitToComplete)

Answer (score 0):

[`My.Computer.Audio.Play`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cf1shcah%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a `VB .NET` method and doesn't work with `VBA`.

For playing `WAV`-Files with `VBA` see here:
[How to play a wave file or sound file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443801/how-to-play-a-wave-file-or-sound-file-using-vba)