# vba ms excel sending an email when performance dips below 50%

Tags: excel, email, vba

Thank you for the wonderful website.

Are you able to assist with the following?

(1) I would like my MS Excel spreadsheet to send an email when aggregate performance (of 10 key performance indicators) goes below 50% (a warning to my workers that performance is slipping).

(2) This performance is measured on a quarterly basis, therefore as each quarter is updated, an email is automatically sent if performance dips below 50%.

(3) Is there a way of adding a specific sound to the email when it is sent?

I would really appreciate your assistance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what SO is about...

Answer (score -1):

You should be more specific on what you mean by "send an email". There are multiple ways to generate automated emails in VBA. Check out this link: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

As for playing a sound when the email is sent, you can achieve this by specifying a audio file and then playing it after the mail is sended. Here is some reference:[How to play a wave file or sound file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443801/how-to-play-a-wave-file-or-sound-file-using-vba)